# csrf токен ошибка в генерации

Tags: php, csrf

Всем привет, написал небольшой код:

```
session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['token']) || !isset($_SESSION['token'])){
            $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['csrf_token'])){
        if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['csrf_token'])) {
            die();
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
```

но возникает проблема с последней проверкой, она даже если по условию не должна срабатывать, то всё равно почему то срабатывает и генерирует новое значение ( как так происходит я не знаю но почему то это именно так и работает ( звучит глупо ) ) 
хотел бы понять, в чём ошибка
и нужно ли вообще генерировать токен каждый раз при обновлении страницы или нужно генерировать после успешной/не успешной сверки токенов

Comment: какая-то сомнительная у вас реализация от `CSRF`-атаки.

Comment: В чем проявляется сомнительность? Генерируется токен по хешу, далее сверяется с тем что уже есть в форме

Comment: Как вы проверили, что у вас срабатывает последняя проверка? У вас значение может генерироваться в ТРЁХ местах в коде — как вы выяснили, в каком именно?

Comment: В 1 месте генерируется при отсутствии изначально, во всех последующих операциях генерируется либо во 2 либо в 3 месте, дальше я просто закоментил последнее место генерации и все работает

Comment: Как минимум в том, что мне достаточно удалить из формы инпут с `csrf_token` и все будет работать.

Comment: Хм, да точно, идиотский косяк... попробую по другому переписать